# How do I flatten nested tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I sum the phone and email with the correspondent name of this list:

```
list_key_value = [['Jibs', ('251871', 'jibs@stack.com')], 
                  ['Marco', ('0000000', 'marco@live.com')], 
                  ['Richard', ('099099', 'richar@hotmail.com')]]
```

Like this:

```
[['Jibs', '251871', 'jibs@stack.com'], 
 ['Marco', '0000000', 'marco@live.com'],
 ['Richard', '099099', 'richar@hotmail.com']]
```

Since it came from this command in Python 3.5:

```
list_key_value=[ [k,v] for k,v in dct.items()]
print(list_key_value)
```

Comment: what are you trying to sum? I don't see anything other than extracting the elements in each tuple

Comment: `[[i[0]]+list(i[1]) for i in data]`

Comment: The question should be left  so the OP can clarify what they mean by *sum the phone and email*

Comment: IIRC, Python 3.5 permits unpacking using `[k, *v]`

Comment: @padraic I agree that the description isn't good, but the expected output makes the meaning clear, IMHO.

Comment: @PM2Ring, yes but the OP's last question was closed for being unclear, they need to learn how to ask a question properly.

Comment: @padraic Ah, I see. Good call.

Comment: Ok the edit is done so you can understand what I mean from the title.

Comment: @Zah how can use delete command on your code list_key_value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.5 you can do

```
list_key_value = [[name, *tp] for (name, tp) in list_key_value]
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to unpack the nested list, which you can use multiple value unpacking within your list comprehension, for that aim:

```
list_key_value=[[k,i,j] for k,(i,j) in dct.items()]
```

Comment: it brings the following error: NameError: name 'lst_key_value' is not defined

Comment: The OP never edited. @Phyti, can you fix your question so it actually makes sense

Comment: @Phyti Maybe you are still trying to
    print(list_key_value)

Comment: @Phyti How did you tried that? pls check the edit for direct way.

Comment: @Kasramvd this is how I done it: s = [[i,j,k] for i,(j,k) in lst_key_value]
    print(s)

Answer (score 0):

More uglier method indeed, but the ends justify the means.

I just put it here, No harm done.

```
lst = [['Jibs', ('251871', 'jibs@stack.com')], ['Marco', ('0000000', 'marco@live.com')], ['Richard', ('099099', 'richar@hotmail.com')]]
new_lst = []
for elem in lst:

    temp_lst = []
    for i in elem:   

        if isinstance(i, tuple):
            temp_lst.extend(i)
        else:
            temp_lst.append(i)
    new_lst.append(temp_lst)
print new_lst

# [['Jibs', '251871', 'jibs@stack.com'], ['Marco', '0000000', 'marco@live.com'], ['Richard', '099099', 'richar@hotmail.com']]
```

Comment: it works but the code is just too extensive and complicated I prefer something like Kasramvd done, can you simplify it?. Thank you & Merry Xmas

Comment: Actually it is complicated because of the method I use and I don't think it is simplifiable, but no worries, I also wouldn't use this method myself. Just to study on, that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

@TanveerAlam solved the problem, although @Kasramvd solution is pending from further explanation:

```
[[i[0]]+list(i[1]) for i in list_key_value]
```